# csv data processing in spark standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark

I have two node and Let's call A(192.168.2.100) and B(192.168.2.200).
A is for a master and a worker.
in A node

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master
```

B is for a woker

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker
```

my app is need to load cav file to process
in node A,

```
./spark-submit --class "myApp" --master spark://192.168.2.100:7077 /spark/app.jar
```

But It comes error with "need csv file in B".
Is there any way to to share this file to node B? 
Do Really I need yarn of mesos to do this?

Comment: You probably need `HDFS`. However you can solve this easily sending all those files to your nodes by using `scp` or an `ansible`.

Comment: copying file to all nodes is not what I want. Thanks It really helped me

Comment: Since my nodes are on single machine and no need to make cluster to do this. I decided to process in a node with multi workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the diagram shows bellow: all the data files you want to process should be accessible from all of your workers [ and be sure that your driver can be reachable from your worker ]

so here, you need to put your data files into a place from where workers can read data, in most situations, we put data files into HDFS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As stated before that file has to be available on every node. So you either have multiple copies, one per node or you use an external hadoop data source (HDFS, Cassandra, Amazon s3). There is another easier solution. You can use NFS and mount a remote drive/partition/location to every node. This way you don't need to have multiple copies and you don't have to learn about an external storage. You can even use [sshfs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) if you want to have a secure mount point over ssh.